# Find the dimension of $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> let  $V$  be  a real vector  space  and $v_1 , v_2 ,......, v_{16} \in V$. Assume  that  $\sum_{i=1}^{8} a_{2i-1}v_{2i-1} = 0$  has  infinitely   many solution  and $\sum_{i=1}^{8} a_{2i}v_{2i} =0 $ has  a unique  solution. Find the  maximum  possible  dimension  of $W:= Span \{v_1,v_2,.......,v_{16}\}$ ?

My try :
$\sum_{i=1}^{8} a_{2i}v_{2i} =0 $ has  a unique  solution that  mean it is linearly independent  so   the  maximum  possible  dimension  of $W:= Span \{v_1,v_2,.......,v_{16}\}= 8$

Is its  true ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Why can't the odd indices add to the dimension of $W$?

Comment: Yes; but only up to a point ;-)

Comment: @Calvin pliz elaborate more

Comment: @Messififa if there are infinitely many solutions then at least there is one $v_{2i-1}$ that is not independent so $W:= Span \{v_{2i-1}\}< 8$